# Gel all the values of Many2Many intermediate table with their respective name

Tags: django

I have the following database structure:

```
Products
--------
id name
1  prodA
2  prodB

Products_Invoices
-----------------
product_id Invoice_id
1             1
2             1

Invoices
--------
id name
1  InvA
2  InvB
```

Which is most correct way to retrieve all the values of the Products_Invoices table but bring the names of their respective row in parent tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated that you have

```
products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)
```

You can do the following:

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.all()

for invoice in invoices:
    for product in invoice.products.all():
        print(product.name)
```

For efficiency, you can also prefetch all the products for the invoice using prefetch_related

```
 invoices = Invoice.objects.all().prefetch_related('products')
```

Comment: But there is not ProductInvoice model. Its only a table. How can this work?

Comment: In invoices model there is products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)